# Airflow task still running even after the endpoint process is completed

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-run

I have an airflow task using SimpleHTTPOperator hitting a service in Google Cloud Run.
I checked in Cloud Run Logs, the service itself is completed in 12 minutes but airflow task keep running up and i need to manually mark it to success.

Any idea what i should check?
I'm new to airflow so i have no idea which logs i should check since there's no useful information from the task log.

I use LocalExecutor to run the DAGs.

Comment: Can you please share the code of the operator?

Answer (score 1):

In my team, we are using the HTTP Operator. However, we also created a custom operator based on it to call Google Cloud Run.

We have many dags that need to make multiple cloud run calls to do API calls for data extraction. Airflow calls Cloud Run and Cloud Run calls an API.

For some of these tasks, when the response time is higher than 8 minutes, Cloud Run sends a 200 back to Airflow, but the task keeps running indefinitely.

One suggestion we got from Google Cloud Support was using HttpSensor instead of HttpOperator. Aparrently, the operator run the tasks run asynchronously, but sensors can wait for some event and completion of tasks. You could try to use HttpSensor and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue, I guessed I could give more detail than the initial post. My team is heavily using Cloud composer, for some application we need to insert data from Bigquery to a MSQL db in azure (driver 17) requiring some annoying drivers.

Since there isn't a clean way to install this on composer 2, I used a cloud run application. I call that cloud run application from airflow to actually insert the data over to Azure.

```py
cloudrun_endpoints = ["update_staging", "update_production"]

@dag(schedule_interval="45 3 * * *", start_date=dates.days_ago(1))
def bq_to_azure():
 get_cloud_run_token = bash.BashOperator(
        task_id="get_cloud_run_token",
        bash_command=f'gcloud auth print-identity-token "--audiences={cloudrun_uri}"',
    )
    token = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_cloud_run_token') }}"
    cloud_run_tasks = [
        HttpSensor(
            task_id=f"{endpoint}",
            http_conn_id="xxxx",
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"},
            endpoint=endpoint,
            response_check=lambda response:  response.json()["job_status"] == "done" or response.status_code != 200,
            poke_interval=5,
            method="POST",
        )
        for endpoint in cloudrun_endpoints
    ]

    chain(get_cloud_run_token, *cloud_run_tasks)
```

Basically if the request takes a bit of time, most of the time airflow just gets stuck, as in the task doing the http call stays in running mode, while I can see the request being finished with status 200 in cloud run logs...

For now I'm just planning to actually deploy the docker application to GKE instead of cloud run.

Edit: This happens with either gen1 or gen2 cloud run.